# Codeigniter upload not accepting .doc files

Tags: codeigniter, file-upload, mime-types

I’m getting the following error when I try to upload:

“The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.”.

**Here is my mime for .doc:**

‘doc’ => array(‘application/msword’,‘application/doc’,‘appl/text’,‘application/vnd.msword’,‘application/word’,‘application/winword’,‘application/vnd.ms-word’,‘application/x-msw6’,‘application/x-msword’),

As you can see I already tried to make up for it by adding more mimes. I have no idea what the problem can be… the file is .doc. Note that uploading pdf's do work! I'm also using a mac.

**Here is my code:**

```
$sntError = $this->uploadFile($id,'notes','doc|pdf|docx');

private function uploadFile ($id,$input,$extensions) {
 $this->load->library('upload');
 $config['allowed_types'] = $extensions;
 $config['upload_path'] = './upload/sermon/'. $input;
 $config['file_name'] = $input .'-'. $id;
 $config['max_size'] = '10000';
 $config['overwrite'] = true;
 $this->upload->initialize($config);
 $uploaded = $this->upload->do_upload($input);

 $errors = $this->upload->display_errors('<div class="error">', '</div>');

 if (!$errors && $uploaded) {
  $fileData = $this->upload->data();
  $this->saveSermonAttachments($id,$input,$fileData['file_name']);
 } else {
  return $errors;
 }
}
```

Comment: If i'm not mistaken, the `data()` will return the content of file even if the upload terminates with error. Can you check the content of the data and see the [file_type]?

Comment: Thanks dude. That helped me find the problem. Apparently the file type was text/plain. So I just added that to the approved mimes for .doc. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did print_r($fileData); to figure out what the .doc file_type was. It was "text/plain," so I added that to my mimes.php and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change the order of the extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to config---->mimes.php

```
            'doc'   =>  'application/msword',
            'docx'  =>  array('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document', 'application/zip'),
            'xlsx'  =>  array('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet', 'application/zip'),
            'word'  =>  array('application/msword', 'application/octet-stream'),
```